# perl \@ escape sequence

Tags: perl, escaping

I've got a perl script with something like the following:

```
" \"blah\@$string;blah\" "
```

But I'm not sure what the `\@` is doing/supposed to do.

I've tried googling '`\@`' but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Not really an answer, but I'd personally write that string as `qq["blah\@$string;blah"]` to avoid the need to escape the double-quotes at the beginning. In Perl, qq[] is the same as "" and you can choose the delimiters you prefer: qq[], qq(), qq{}, qq//, qq^^, qq!!, qq||, etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It causes the `@` to mean "An at sign" instead of "Dereference `$string` as an arrayref".

Answer (score 6):

The backslash before the `@` tells Perl to treat it literally, otherwise it will treat it as an array. If the `@` is followed by an `$` it will be treated as an array reference (a string holding a reference to an array). If you print it out it may be clearer (I have changed your code to use `qq||`):

```
my $string = 'i-am-a-string';

print qq| "blah\@$string;blah" |; # with backslash
#  "blah@i-am-a-string;blah"

print qq| "blah@$string;blah" |; # no backslash
# Can't use string ("i-am-a-string") as an ARRAY ref

$string = [1,2,3]; # string now an array reference

print qq| "blah\@$string;blah" |; # with backslash
#  "blah@ARRAY(0x803bc0);blah"    # ARRAY(0x803bc0) is where (1,2,3) lives

print qq| "blah@$string;blah" |; # no backslash
# "blah1 2 3;blah"
```